# BIRT: how to connect to SQL Server 2005

Tags: database, eclipse, sql-server-2005, birt

I am having trouble writing the database URL for a SQL Server 2005 database when creating a data source for a BIRT report. The URL I have written looks like this:

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://host:port;databasename=name;user=userName;password=yourPwd
```

I placed the sqljdbc.jar (jdbc 3.0) in the following location:

```
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.6.1.v20100909/drivers
```

When I press the "Test Connection" button in the "Edit Data Source" dialog I get the following error:

```
The selected driver cannot parse the given url.
```

Can you give me any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: No problem. You might also want to check out the FAQ link at the top of the page if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already know, the URL is incorrect. I haven't worked with Java for a while now, but your URL looks a lot like a connection string in .Net. However, a connection string would also contain the instance name (probably SQLEXPRESS) and possibly the authentication method.

A quick Google search turned up [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspxl), a page on MSDN that deals with building that connection URL of yours. Hopefully, it will help.

Comment: Now it works! The only thing I did wrong was to add the :microsoft to the protocol.